# How to handle endless sub routes & nested routes in Flutter Web using the go_router package

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-go-router, flutter-routes

I'm building a simple file storage application like DropBox. The base file path for assets would be mywebsite.com/assets. I want to be able to also handle dynamic paths like the following

- mywebsite.com/assets/folder
- mywebsite.com/assets/folder/private
- mywebsite.com/assets/folder/private/2023
- mywebsite.com/assets/folder/private/2023/initial

Where 'folder', 'private', '2023' & 'initial' are all folders.